# How to Set Permission for a Role to False

Tags: java, discord-jda

How do I set a role's permission to false. For example, I want to create a muted role that cannot send messages.

I know how to create a role with Permission.MESSAGE_WRITE to true but not false:

```
e.getGuild().createRole().setName("Muted").setPermissions(Permission.MESSAGE_WRITE).queue();
```

Comment: Everyone has all permissions from all their roles(including `@everyone`). If you want to make a muted role, you may need to use per-channel permission overrides as those can be denied.

Comment: Oh, so there is no way to make a role with this permission turned off: [image](https://imgur.com/a/nJEZn0F)?

Comment: You can make sure that the user has the permission with no roles or explicitely deny it for the muted role on every single channel.

Answer (score 0):

Use TextChannelCreateEvent to make sure when a text-channel is created the Muted role does not have permission to send messages.

Code:

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChannelCreate(TextChannelCreateEvent e) {
        try {
            TextChannel channel = e.getChannel();
            Guild guild = e.getGuild();
            Role role = guild.getRolesByName("Muted", false).get(0);
            channel.createPermissionOverride(role).setDeny(Permission.MESSAGE_WRITE).queue();

        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException error) {
            e.getGuild().createRole().setName("Muted").queue();
        }
    }
```

Major credits to @dan1st.